# How to handle the loading bar in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native 
I'm fetching API through server and data comes and i'm showing in my app.
I'm using loading bar when its goes false then data set in my app
But, all data is not coming instantly.
Its taking little time to appear after loading is done.
So, How can i increase my time for loading bar.
So, that when my loading is goes false then the all data display at one go.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make a `loading overlay component` which can be used everywhere.

For example

```
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native'

_renderSpinner = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: screenwidth / 2,
                bottom: 0}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator color={Colors.Primary} size={'large'}/>
            </View>
        )
    }

render () {
     return (
                {yourLoaderVaribale && this._renderSpinner()}    
     )
}
```